# Maintain item maintenance for a items in a class created by developer using subclass per item

Tags: php, php-5.3

If anyone has an idea, I couldn't think of a better way to phase the question.

I'll try to not make this to complicated an explination.

I'm writing a "quotes" class that is the main class. This class has "overall" functions that preform calculations based on "items" stored in its array. Suffice it to say, the end-developer will call it as `$q = new apiQuote/quote()`.

Then, before it's of any use, the first item must be added and it's properties set so it can do it's "own" calculations. Something like `$q->createItem()`. Once the item is created with this call, an "item" of the class "item" is added to an array in "quotes" named "items".

The currently editable item, `$q->item` is always the last one added to the array via the `createItem` method. Which looks like:

```
public function createNewItem() {
    $this->items[] = new item();
    $this->item = $this->items[count($this->items)-1];
}
```

I added `setItem` method, whereby the parameter would be an integer representing item index in the array and would set `$q->item` to the item index chosen. This works, but still seems "not as productive" as I'd like".

What I'm curious about, is if anyone has any suggestions on a better way to go about this. I tried looking for a "cards/deck" php example, but all I could find was array shuffles, which is kinda useless here. I know how to do such associations in .NET and thought this would be just as easy, but I don't have the same property abilities in PHP that I have in a .NET language, thus negating what I'm used to in created this kind of "class/subclass[items]" type structure.

Really I would just like to know if anyone has done anything similar and if I'm doing things to the "best of ability" or if there might be a better way, via PHP, to allow an "end-developer" to call on one main class and create a list "items" based on a subclass that can later be used for methods of the main class?

I really hope this sums it all up well and I havn't gone outside the guidelines of "question asking" here, but I can't think of a better place, other than maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to pose such a question and get great developer feed back. If y'all feel I need move it to Code Review, let me know. My main reason for choosing this over CR is this site tends to get faster responses.

Perhaps a view of what I have and what I "might" like to see:

### Way it works now

```
$q = new apiQuote\quote(TRUE);

$q->createNewItem();
$q->item->totalHeight = 100;
$q->item->totalWidth = 250;
...

$q->createNewItem();
$q->item->totalHeight = 300;
$q->item->set_coverage('25%');
...
$q->setItem(1);
$q->item->totalHeight = 250;
...
$q->getTotalsCurv(); // an array to create a graph curve of totals from each item
```

### What I "think" I might like:

```
$q = new apiQuote\quote(TRUE);

$q->items[] = new apiQuote\item();
$q->items[0]->totalHeight = 100;
$q->items[0]->totalWidth = 250;
...

$q->items[] = new apiQuote\item();
$q->items[1]->totalHeight = 300;
$q->items[1]->set_coverage('25%');
...
$q->items[0]->totalHeight = 250;
...
$q->getTotalsCurv();
```

However, something like the second idea mean leaving the "items" array public, which could lead to a vast amount of "other" problems as I'm trying to set this whole thing up to be "near dummy proof". Thus the usage of `protected` variables with specific `get/set` methods as if they where C# properties.

Comment: Not sure what your question really is. You already have a solution (not shown but it seems pretty simple) and you're looking for a better one? Is there a reason why you want to restrict editing to only the last item added?

Comment: @Technoh I had a typo, but fixed it and since added method for "editing items" in the array, but again, I just don't feel like this is the best way to go about it. Though I'm not sure I can describe, or even think of a better way, thus my prose for the question, if anyone has done this and if they have a "better way".

Comment: How do you do such associations in .NET?

Comment: @PatrickEvans something like 
`Dim deck as new Deck()
Dim card as deck.card()
card.prop = "whatever"
deck.add(card);`

Comment: Ouch, this is BASIC :)

Comment: Currently `$this->item` holds the latest item as a *copy*. If you "do" anything with `$this->item` the changes will not reflect in the corresponding `items[count($this->items)-1]` array element. You could alternatively set `$this->item` to be a *reference* on the last array element with `$this->item = &$this->items[count($this->items)-1];` and then any edit-method you write could simply operate on `$this->item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is how to identify an "item" outside of the quote instance. And by using its array index you feel you are going to run into the problems. And you will, when you will try to delete an item. It would successfully invalidate any index already known/stored outside. The simplest patch to it is to give every item a unique ID and store them in the map instead of storing it as a vector.

Also, in your solution item by itself cannot provide you with any helpful information how to access this item in your collection of items (a quote).

```
public function createNewItem() {
  static $counter;
  $id = $counter++;
  return $this->item = $this->items[$id] = new item($id);
}

public function editItem($id) {
 return $this->item = $this->items[$id];
}

public function removeItem($id) {
 $this->item = null;
 unset($this->item[$id]);
}
```

Alternatively I recommend you not to reinvent the wheel and take a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

and here in specific
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

Anything that implements Iterator interface can be iterated with foreach

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Comment: Ah I see, hadn't really thought about that yet. Thanx, looking into (testing) this now. Thanks for the links, didn't even know this about PHP!

Comment: Loving the `SplObjectStorage` playing with it now!

Comment: I selected your answer, but mainly for the link to SplObjectStorage, as this is what I'm now implementing and loving how well I can manipulate it withing the class and create FAR less room for end-developer error!

Answer (score 1):

Ah well you could return the new item from the `createItem` function.

An equivalent of your .NET example would be to simply return the new item

```
public function createNewItem() {
    $this->items[] = new item();
    $this->item = $this->items[count($this->items)-1];
    return $this->items[count($this->items)-1];
}
```

then you could do

```
$item = $q->createNewItem();
$item->totalHeight = 100;
...
```

And as you are already adding the new item to the array from within `createNewItem` so no need for something like $q->add($item);

And to get at any other item you could do a

```
function getItem($index){
   return $this->items[count($this->items)-1];
}
$otheritem = $q->getItem(3);
$otheritem->totalHeight = 100;
```

Comment: You don't need to return objects as references. They are always returned as references. Reference must be used only for scalars and arrays.

Comment: Yea i thought as much but wasnt sure, was just looking it up too to see if that was the case.